# how to find index ( id ) of generic column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with name rating as this.

[image: a busy cat]

I am writing the query like this

```
SELECT user_id, sum(score) as score
FROM quiz_rashad.rating
group by user_id
order by score desc
```

then how I get rating index of the 12th user?
Thank you for helping.

Comment: What are you using ? SQL- Server or MYSQL?

Comment: I am using MySql version 8

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Am I the only one that didn't understand anything?

Comment: Rating index?? You mean rank right?

Comment: Yes I mean rating specific users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, that "the 12th user" means the user with the ID 12:

In MySQL 8.0+ you can use `dense_rank()`.

```
SELECT x.rating_index
       FROM (SELECT r.user_id,
                    dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum(r.score) DESC) rating_index
                    FROM quiz_rashad.rating r
                    GROUP BY r.user_id) x
       WHERE x.user_id = 12;
```

---

Edit:

For MySQL 5.7 you have to use subqueries getting the distinct count of total scores greater than or equal the total score for the user with ID 12.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT x.score) rating_index
       FROM (SELECT r.user_id,
                    sum(r.score) score
                    FROM quiz_rashad.rating r
                    GROUP BY r.user_id) x
       WHERE x.score >= (SELECT sum(r.score)
                                FROM quiz_rashad.rating r
                                WHERE r.user_id = 12)
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: As I understand the OP they want a ranking over their users. The more total score a user has, the higher their ranking. The total score is the sum of the individual scores in the table. The inner `SELECT` calculates that ranking for all users. Now the question is: What rank does the user with ID 12 have? That is, the inner `SELECT` is queried for the user with ID 12. But that's a best guess. My understanding might be wrong too.

Comment: Sorry my mysql version is 5.7

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `LIMIT` with `OFFSET` here:

```
SELECT user_id, SUM(score) AS score
FROM quiz_rashad.rating
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 11;
```

This answer assumes that what you really want here is the record with the twelfth rank.  It also assumes that no two users would be tied for the same score.